# Convertir reporte tabular (matriz) a formato de tabla simple

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un reporte tabular, también llamado matriz o "crosstab". Por ejemplo, en los encabezados de las columnas se indica el nombre del cliente, en los encabezados de los renglones el nombre del producto y en la intersección el número de productos vendidos a cada cliente.

```
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   |     A      |     B     |     C     |     D     |
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 |            | Cliente 1 | Cliente 2 | Cliente 3 |
| 2 | Producto 1 | 4         | 2         | 6         |
| 3 | Producto 2 | 7         | 8         | 6         |
| 4 | Producto 3 | 6         | 3         | 5         |
| 5 | Producto 4 | 3         | 3         | 8         |
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Requiero pasar los datos a formato de tabla simple, es decir, una columna para los encabezados de las filas, una columna para los encabezados de las columnas y una columna para los valores, como se muestra a continuación:

```
+----+---------------------+------------------------+---------+
|    |          A          |           B            |    C    |
+----+---------------------+------------------------+---------+
|  1 | Encabezados de fila | Encabezados de columna | Valores |
|  2 | Producto 1          | Cliente 1              | 4       |
|  3 | Producto 2          | Cliente 2              | 8       |
|  4 | Producto 3          | Cliente 3              | 5       |
|  5 | Producto 4          | Cliente 1              | 3       |
|  6 | Producto 1          | Cliente 2              | 2       |
|  7 | Producto 2          | Cliente 3              | 6       |
|  8 | Producto 3          | Cliente 1              | 6       |
|  9 | Producto 4          | Cliente 2              | 3       |
| 10 | Producto 1          | Cliente 3              | 6       |
| 11 | Producto 2          | Cliente 1              | 7       |
| 12 | Producto 3          | Cliente 2              | 3       |
| 13 | Producto 4          | Cliente 3              | 8       |
+----+---------------------+------------------------+---------+
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto usando las funciones de hoja de cálculo de Google?

## Aclaraciones

Pregunta inspirada en
[How do you create a “reverse pivot” in Google Sheets? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722/1595451) y en experiencia personal.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [este archivo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JzjaQTKV8sRVda2vrhsKAQIl6qGs56ttftsnfI0w3jg/edit?usp=sharing) se encuentra un ejemplo de como realizar la conversión. A continuación se describen los pasos a seguir.

1. Crear una hoja y llamarla "Aux".
2. En la hoja creada en paso anterior agregar las siguientes fórmulas:
   Se asume que los datos de reporte tabular se encuentran en una hoja llamada `data`, que la celda A1 está en blanco y que no incluye datos ajenos al reporte.
   A1: `=COUNTA(data!A:A)` Número de renglones.
   A2: `=COUNTA(data!1:1)` Número de columnas.
   A3: `=CELL("address",data!A1)` Cálculo intermedio.
   A4: `=LEFT(A3,FIND("!",A3)-1)` Nombre de la hoja con los datos fuente.
3. Crear una nueva hoja
4. En la nueva hoja agregar lo siguiente
   A1: Encabezados de fila
   A2:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  VLOOKUP(
    MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A1)+1+1,
    {(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1+1))),INDIRECT(Aux!A4&"!R1C1:R"&Aux!A1+1&"C"&Aux!A2+1,false)},
    2
  )
)
```

B1: Encabezados de columna
B2:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  VLOOKUP(
    SIGN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))),
    {(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1+1))),INDIRECT(Aux!A4&"!R1C1:R"&Aux!A1+1&"C"&Aux!A2+1,false)},
    MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A2)+1+2
  )
)
```

C1: Valores
C2:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  VLOOKUP(
    MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A1)+1+1,
    {(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1+1))),INDIRECT(Aux!A4&"!R1C1:R"&Aux!A1+1&"C"&Aux!A2+1,false)},
    MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A2)+1+2
  )
)
```

## Descripción de los constructos utilizados

`ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))` determina una matriz de números consecutivos cuyo tamaño corresponde al número de filas que se requieren en el resultado final.

`MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A1)+1` determina el índice del encabezado de la fila.

`MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1*Aux!A2))-1,Aux!A2)+1` determina el índice del encabezado de la columna.

`{(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&Aux!A1+1))),INDIRECT(Aux!A4&"!R1C1:R"&Aux!A1+1&"C"&Aux!A2+1,false)}` crea una matriz cuya primera columna es el índice de la fila y las siguientes corresponde a los datos del reporte tabular.

Answer (score 1):

Yo he montado una solución a tu problema con google apps script que creo que es más sencilla que la propuesta hasta ahora.

En el editor de código de la hoja ponle lo siguiente:

```
function onOpen() 
{
    Convert();
};

function onEdit() 
{
    Convert();
};

function Convert()
{
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet_ori = spread.getSheetByName("Original");
  var sheet_dst = spread.getSheetByName("Destino");

  var values_ori = sheet_ori.getDataRange().getValues();

  var names = values_ori[0];
  var cont = 1;

  for(var i = 1 ; i < values_ori.length ; ++i)
  { 
    var row = values_ori[i];
    var caption = row[0];
    for(var j = 1 ; j < row.length ; ++j)
    {
        sheet_dst.getRange(cont, 1).setValue(caption);
        sheet_dst.getRange(cont, 2).setValue(names[j]);
        sheet_dst.getRange(cont, 3).setValue(row[j]);
        cont++;
    }
  }
}
```

Graba el archivo de código. Cada vez que alguien modifique la hoja "Original" se actualizará la hoja "Destino".

Espero que te sirva.

La pregunta me ha resultado muy interesante desde el punto de vista didáctico asi que la he usado para publicar en mi blog... espero que no te moleste:
http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/como-convertir-un-matriz-de-datos-en.html

Comment: No me molesta, al contrario me siento honrado. Cabe mencionar que la forma apropiada de atribuir incluye liga al post, como lo has hecho, pero también mencionar el nombre e incluir un link al perfil del autor. Más detalles en http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ , P.D. yo debo de seguir mas frecuentemente mi propio consejo :)

Comment: Nombre y link puestos.. aún soy novato.... recuerda marcar alguna solución como válida si te resulta útil :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema pero me encontré una solución que ya apliqué en con un script. Aquí viene todo cómo hacerlo y le doy el respectivo mérito a Viktor Camp

Te sugiero veas el link y ahí te lleva al ejemplo y todo muy bien explicado

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954722/how-do-you-create-a-reverse-pivot-in-google-sheets

```
/**
* Unpivot a pivot table of any size.
*
* @param {A1:D30} data The pivot table.
* @param {1} fixColumns Number of columns, after which pivoted values begin. 
Default 1.
* @param {1} fixRows Number of rows (1 or 2), after which pivoted values 
begin. Default 1.
* @param {"city"} titlePivot The title of horizontal pivot values. Default 
"column".
* @param {"distance"[,...]} titleValue The title of pivot table values. 
Default "value".
* @return The unpivoted table
* @customfunction
*/
function unpivot(data,fixColumns,fixRows,titlePivot,titleValue) {  
var fixColumns = fixColumns || 1; // how many columns are fixed
var fixRows = fixRows || 1; // how many rows are fixed
var titlePivot = titlePivot || 'column';
var titleValue = titleValue || 'value';
var ret=[],i,j,row,uniqueCols=1;

// we handle only 2 dimension arrays
if (!Array.isArray(data) || data.length < fixRows || !Array.isArray(data[0]) 
|| data[0].length < fixColumns)
throw new Error('no data');
// we handle max 2 fixed rows
  if (fixRows > 2)
    throw new Error('max 2 fixed rows are allowed');

  // fill empty cells in the first row with value set last in previous 
columns (for 2 fixed rows)
  var tmp = '';
  for (j=0;j<data[0].length;j++)
    if (data[0][j] != '') 
      tmp = data[0][j];
    else
      data[0][j] = tmp;

  // for 2 fixed rows calculate unique column number
  if (fixRows == 2)
  {
    uniqueCols = 0;
    tmp = {};
    for (j=fixColumns;j<data[1].length;j++)
      if (typeof tmp[ data[1][j] ] == 'undefined')
      {
        tmp[ data[1][j] ] = 1;
        uniqueCols++;
      }
  }

  // return first row: fix column titles + pivoted values column title + 
values column title(s)
  row = [];
    for (j=0;j<fixColumns;j++) row.push(fixRows == 2 ? data[0][j]||data[1] 
[j] : data[0][j]); // for 2 fixed rows we try to find the title in row 1 and 
row 2
    for (j=3;j<arguments.length;j++) row.push(arguments[j]);
  ret.push(row);

  // processing rows (skipping the fixed columns, then dedicating a new row 
for each pivoted value)
  for (i=fixRows;i<data.length && data[i].length > 0 && data[i][0];i++)
  {
    row = [];
    for (j=0;j<fixColumns && j<data[i].length;j++)
      row.push(data[i][j]);
    for (j=fixColumns;j<data[i].length;j+=uniqueCols)
      ret.push( 
        row.concat([data[0][j]]) // the first row title value
        .concat(data[i].slice(j,j+uniqueCols)) // pivoted values
      );
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Javier por pasar y dejar tu aporte. Cabe destacar que la pregunta trata sobre funciones de la hoja de cálculo. En cualquier caso es bueno tener en un sólo lugar tener tanto la solución con funciones incluidas (built-in) como con scripts.