# ¿Transponer filas a columnas de forma automática? EXCEL 2010 / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Amigos, recurro a las mentes sabias para un planteamiento que he intentado mucho a través de las funciones de EXCEL 2010 pero no me resulta e imagino que con una macro vba podría ser, pero no domino el lenguaje.

Problema: Poseo un Excel de calendarios ordenados filas de la siguiente forma:

```
Código | Descrip | Lunes  | Martes |Miércole| Jueves | Viernes| Sábado | Domingo| Lunes  | Martes |
Semana1|L a V am.|08001800|08001800|08001800|08001800|08001800|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|
Semana2|L a V pm.|15302100|15302100|15302100|15302100|21000800|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|
Semana3|L a V am.|09001900|09001900|09001900|09001900|09001900|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|08001800|08001800|
```

Es decir, es un turno de trabajo. Para facilitar la carga masiva de datos requiero lo mismo pero en columnas de la siguiente forma:

```
Código | Descrip  | Tramo  | Secuencia  | Cantidad Días
Semana1|L a V am. |08001800| 1          |5
Semana1|L a V am. |DESCANSO| 2          |2
Semana2|L a V pm. |15302100| 1          |4
Semana2|L a V pm. |21000800| 2          |1
Semana2|L a V pm. |DESCANSO| 3          |2
Semana3|L a V am. |09001900| 1          |5
Semana3|L a V am. |DESCANSO| 2          |2
Semana3|L a V am. |08001800| 3          |2
```

Explicación: EJ: Semana1 dice que de lunes a viernes asiste de 08:00 a 18:00 (5 días), luego tiene 2 días de descanso "DESCANSO". columna secuencia sirve para identificar el orden de lo que se agrega y además saber cuando cambia el tramo, es decir, el primer cambio se genera de viernes a sábado.

Comment: Este sitio es para preguntas sobre preguntas acerca de problemas concretos no para solicitar "links". Por favor, edita tu pregunta. Más detalles sobre cómo preguntar en [ask] y sobre la temática del sitio en [help/on-topic].

Comment: Lo solicité así para que no pensaran que solo quiero la solución y ya, puesto que busqué y no encontré y quizá alguien pudiese guiarme y como no poseo un avance del código porque no tengo un dominio del lenguaje que solicito, se podría mal interpretar.

Comment: No entiendo el resultado, lo de Secuencia.

Comment: Esa forma de solicitar ayuda la puedes usar en el [chat] pero no aquí. Sería bueno que incluyeras en tu pregunta una breve descripción de qué y cómo buscaste y aunque no tengas un dominio del lenguaje, deberías consultar la documentación. Si hay algo que no entiendas de la misma, lo puedes incluir en la pregunta mientras esté en el contexto de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Transponer se refiere a cambiar las filas a columnas, pero lo que quieres hacer es otra cosa. Dependiendo de "los antecedentes" del autor puedes encontrar publicaciones sobre como hacer esto con términos como normalizar, "unpivot" (¿despivotar?), convertir a tabla simple, entre otros.

Esto se puede hacer de varias formas, pero si cuentas con Excel 2016, en teoría esto es más fácil ya que se ha introducido "Get & Transform" en la pestaña Data del listón (ribbon).  Los detalles paso a paso además de enlaces información adicional en [Learn how to unpivot static tables in Excel 2016](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/).

Comment: Actualmente poseo la limitancia de Excel 2010, sin embargo, el concepto lo entiendo y buscare sobre ello. gracias

Comment: @EstebanJaramillo: El siguiente es un enlace a una pregunta sobre [google-hoja-de-calculo] y [google-apps-script] el cual te podría dar una idea sobre el algoritmo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6091/65